# How to get JSON response from http.Get

Tags: json, go

I'm trying read JSON data from web, but that code returns empty result. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
package main

import "os"
import "fmt"
import "net/http"
import "io/ioutil"
import "encoding/json"

type Tracks struct {
    Toptracks []Toptracks_info
}

type Toptracks_info struct {
    Track []Track_info
    Attr  []Attr_info
}

type Track_info struct {
    Name       string
    Duration   string
    Listeners  string
    Mbid       string
    Url        string
    Streamable []Streamable_info
    Artist     []Artist_info
    Attr       []Track_attr_info
}

type Attr_info struct {
    Country    string
    Page       string
    PerPage    string
    TotalPages string
    Total      string
}

type Streamable_info struct {
    Text      string
    Fulltrack string
}

type Artist_info struct {
    Name string
    Mbid string
    Url  string
}

type Track_attr_info struct {
    Rank string
}

func get_content() {
    // json data
    url := "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettoptracks&api_key=c1572082105bd40d247836b5c1819623&format=json&country=Netherlands"

    res, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    var data Tracks
    json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
    fmt.Printf("Results: %v\n", data)
    os.Exit(0)
}

func main() {
    get_content()
}
```

Answer (score 371, accepted):

The ideal way is *not* to use `ioutil.ReadAll`, but rather use a decoder on the reader directly. Here's a nice function that gets a url and decodes its response onto a `target` structure.

```
var myClient = &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}

func getJson(url string, target interface{}) error {
    r, err := myClient.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    return json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(target)
}
```

Example use:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar string
}

func main() {
    foo1 := new(Foo) // or &Foo{}
    getJson("http://example.com", foo1)
    println(foo1.Bar)

    // alternately:

    foo2 := Foo{}
    getJson("http://example.com", &foo2)
    println(foo2.Bar)
}
```

You should not be using the default `*http.Client` structure in production as this answer originally demonstrated! (Which is what `http.Get`/etc call to). The reason is that the default client has no timeout set; if the remote server is unresponsive, you're going to have a bad day.

Comment: This was very helpful. It took me a while to get the target right, but I am still new to go. I ended up making a struct, then ```tmp := myStuct{}``` then ```json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&tmp)``` and from there I could use my json.

Comment: It seems like you need to use Uppercase for the names of the items in the struct e.g. `type WebKeys struct {
 Keys []struct {
  X5t string
  X5c []string
 }
}`  even when the actual params in the JSON you're parsing are in lower case. JSON example: `{
 "keys": [{
  "x5t": "foo",
  "x5c": "baaaar"
 }]
}`

Comment: That's correct. Lowercase keys aren't accessible outside of the package they're declared in, `encoding/json` can't set them.

Comment: Won't this leak response body during the error scenario, as the defer statement won't be reached?

Comment: @Roman, no. If an error is returned, the response value is nil. (An error means we couldn't read any valid HTTP response, there's no body to close!) You can test this by pointing .Get() at a non-existent URL. Tis method is demonstrated in the second code block in the [net/http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) docs.

Comment: May I know why we put `var myClient` outside `getJson()` function?

Comment: @NamGVU saves a potential allocation and allows the use of http keep-alive to reuse connections.

Comment: @ConnorPeet You made my day thanks ! I wonder what you meant with "You should not be using the default *http.Client structure in production". Did you mean that one should use `&http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}` or use a whole other library/strategy ?

Comment: Yep, that's the way to do it!

Comment: Just a warning to others - `json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(target)` will *not* return an error for certain types of malformed JSON! I just wasted a few hours trying to understand why I kept getting an empty response - turns out the source JSON had an extra comma where it shouldn't have been. I suggest you use `json.Unmarshal` instead.  There's also a good writeup about other potential dangers of using `json.Decoder` [here](https://ahmet.im/blog/golang-json-decoder-pitfalls/)

Answer (score 32):

Your Problem were the slice declarations in your data `structs` (except for `Track`, they shouldn't be slices...). This was compounded by some rather goofy fieldnames in the fetched json file, which can be fixed via structtags, see  [godoc](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).

The code below parsed the json successfully. If you've further questions, let me know.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/http"
import "io/ioutil"
import "encoding/json"

type Tracks struct {
    Toptracks Toptracks_info
}

type Toptracks_info struct {
    Track []Track_info
    Attr  Attr_info `json: "@attr"`
}

type Track_info struct {
    Name       string
    Duration   string
    Listeners  string
    Mbid       string
    Url        string
    Streamable Streamable_info
    Artist     Artist_info   
    Attr       Track_attr_info `json: "@attr"`
}

type Attr_info struct {
    Country    string
    Page       string
    PerPage    string
    TotalPages string
    Total      string
}

type Streamable_info struct {
    Text      string `json: "#text"`
    Fulltrack string
}

type Artist_info struct {
    Name string
    Mbid string
    Url  string
}

type Track_attr_info struct {
    Rank string
}

func perror(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func get_content() {
    url := "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettoptracks&api_key=c1572082105bd40d247836b5c1819623&format=json&country=Netherlands"

    res, err := http.Get(url)
    perror(err)
    defer res.Body.Close()

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(res.Body)
    var data Tracks
    err = decoder.Decode(&data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%T\n%s\n%#v\n",err, err, err)
        switch v := err.(type){
            case *json.SyntaxError:
                fmt.Println(string(body[v.Offset-40:v.Offset]))
        }
    }
    for i, track := range data.Toptracks.Track{
        fmt.Printf("%d: %s %s\n", i, track.Artist.Name, track.Name)
    }
}

func main() {
    get_content()
}
```

Comment: There is something in the response body.

Comment: In my case, I was missing UPPER-CASE first character in the "struct" fields.

Comment: Answer below is right, using a Decoder directly on the response.Body avoids unnecessary allocations and is generally more ideomatic. Corrected my answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @abourget omg thank you for this comment. Just spend 1 hours looking for problems in parser, confirming with wireshark that response is correct... thanks

Answer (score 24):

You need upper case property names in your structs in order to be used by the json packages.

Upper case property names are `exported properties`.  Lower case property names are not exported.

You also need to pass the your data object by reference (`&data`).

```
package main

import "os"
import "fmt"
import "net/http"
import "io/ioutil"
import "encoding/json"

type tracks struct {
    Toptracks []toptracks_info
}

type toptracks_info struct {
    Track []track_info
    Attr  []attr_info
}

type track_info struct {
    Name       string
    Duration   string
    Listeners  string
    Mbid       string
    Url        string
    Streamable []streamable_info
    Artist     []artist_info
    Attr       []track_attr_info
}

type attr_info struct {
    Country    string
    Page       string
    PerPage    string
    TotalPages string
    Total      string
}

type streamable_info struct {
    Text      string
    Fulltrack string
}

type artist_info struct {
    Name string
    Mbid string
    Url  string
}

type track_attr_info struct {
    Rank string
}

func get_content() {
    // json data
    url := "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettoptracks&api_key=c1572082105bd40d247836b5c1819623&format=json&country=Netherlands"

    res, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    var data tracks
    json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
    fmt.Printf("Results: %v\n", data)
    os.Exit(0)
}

func main() {
    get_content()
}
```

Comment: still not work, is this working for you ? same empty response

Comment: thanks for "You need upper case property names in your structs in order to be used by the json packages."

Answer (score 12):

The results from `json.Unmarshal` (into `var data interface{}`) do not directly match your Go type and variable declarations. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type Tracks struct {
    Toptracks []Toptracks_info
}

type Toptracks_info struct {
    Track []Track_info
    Attr  []Attr_info
}

type Track_info struct {
    Name       string
    Duration   string
    Listeners  string
    Mbid       string
    Url        string
    Streamable []Streamable_info
    Artist     []Artist_info
    Attr       []Track_attr_info
}

type Attr_info struct {
    Country    string
    Page       string
    PerPage    string
    TotalPages string
    Total      string
}

type Streamable_info struct {
    Text      string
    Fulltrack string
}

type Artist_info struct {
    Name string
    Mbid string
    Url  string
}

type Track_attr_info struct {
    Rank string
}

func get_content() {
    // json data
    url := "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettoptracks&api_key=c1572082105bd40d247836b5c1819623&format=json&country=Netherlands"
    url += "&limit=1" // limit data for testing
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    var data interface{} // TopTracks
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("Results: %v\n", data)
    os.Exit(0)
}

func main() {
    get_content()
}
```

Output:

```
Results: map[toptracks:map[track:map[name:Get Lucky (feat. Pharrell Williams) listeners:1863 url:http://www.last.fm/music/Daft+Punk/_/Get+Lucky+(feat.+Pharrell+Williams) artist:map[name:Daft Punk mbid:056e4f3e-d505-4dad-8ec1-d04f521cbb56 url:http://www.last.fm/music/Daft+Punk] image:[map[#text:http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/88137413.png size:small] map[#text:http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/88137413.png size:medium] map[#text:http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/88137413.png size:large] map[#text:http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/88137413.png size:extralarge]] @attr:map[rank:1] duration:369 mbid: streamable:map[#text:1 fulltrack:0]] @attr:map[country:Netherlands page:1 perPage:1 totalPages:500 total:500]]]
```

Comment: FYI `ioutil.ReadAll` is now deprecated in favour of `io.ReadAll`

Answer (score 4):

Ok my dudes, I wasted some time on this because none of the above solutions were working for me.

1. So what the issue for me was as stated above in the examples "Toptracks" in the first struct, I renamed it to "Tracks" to match the first layer.
2. Other issue was in struct "Toptracks_info" with property "Attr", the problem here is that in the response we get "@attr" and you cannot put @ because it's an invalid char for naming properties so I had to add `json:"@attr"` (same thing goes for "#text" in image array
   So the example is :

and main is

```
type Tracks struct {
    Tracks Toptracks_info
}

type Toptracks_info struct {
    Track []Track_info
    Attr  Attr_info `json:"@attr"`
}

type Track_info struct {
    Name       string
    Duration   string
    Listeners  string
    Mbid       string
    Url        string
    Streamable Streamable_info
    Artist     Artist_info
    Image      []Image
    Attr       Track_attr_info
}
type Image struct {
    Text string `json:"#text"`
    Size string
}

type Attr_info struct {
    Country    string
    Page       string
    PerPage    string
    TotalPages string
    Total      string
}

type Streamable_info struct {
    Text      string
    Fulltrack string
}

type Artist_info struct {
    Name string
    Mbid string
    Url  string
}

type Track_attr_info struct {
    Rank string
}


url := "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettoptracks&api_key=xxxxxxxx&format=json&country=Netherlands"

res, err := http.Get(url)

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
var data Tracks
json.Unmarshal(body, &data)

if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
```

It's my first time with Go and it drove me a bit crazy.