# Golang post return json response

Tags: json, curl, go

I'm trying to make a request to my (magento)webserver using golang.

I managed to make a POST request, but however, I'm not getting the same response I'm getting when using CURL from the cmd.
I followed this post ([How to get JSON response in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156371/how-to-get-json-response-in-golang)) which does not give me any response.

So I tried this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

var protocol = "http://"
var baseURL = protocol + "myserver.dev"

func main() {

    fmt.Print("Start API Test on: " + baseURL + "\n")
    r := getCart()
    fmt.Print(r)
}

func getCart() *http.Response {
    resp, err := http.Post(os.ExpandEnv(baseURL+"/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/"), "", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }

    return resp
}
```

This just return the http reponse like

```
{200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Date:[Thu, 04 May 2017 05:30:20 GMT] Content-Type:[application/json; charset=utf-8] Set-Cookie:[PHPSESSID=elklkflekrlfekrlklkl; expires=Thu, 04-May-2017 ...
```

When using `curl -g -X POST "my.dev/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/"` I retrieve some kind of ID which I need to proceed.
How can I get the this curl result in golang?

Comment: What`s the output of curl? Are you sure the server answers the request in JSON?

Comment: @Grasshopper according to the documentation (http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/   ->quoteGuestCartManagementV1) respnse is application/json. It generates a cart id like this e746bf2663fd302aebc3d5a8c8443498

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the `resp.Body` (and don't forget to close it!), ie

```
func main() {
    fmt.Print("Start API Test on: " + baseURL + "\n")
    r := getCart()
    defer r.Body.Close();
    if _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, r.Body); err != nil {
       fmt.Print(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: The `r.Body` is a stream, you need to read FROM it. With `fmt.Print(r.body)` you just print it's address.