# Golang get xml response from http.Get

Tags: xml, go

I am working on a xml parser which gets xml response from RSS feeds
I happened to read some posts on **json.Decode** VS **json.Unmarshal**  [How to get JSON response from http.Get](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31129967/4568140). In short:

1. when data source is http.get which is streams we should use json.decoder, as it might be a very long json
2. if response body is small enough, we can read it all into memory with ioutil.ReadAll and use json.Unmarshal. Also , json.Unmarshal is dealing with **byte/string** not stream

So I have the same question to xml decoding , does the same rule apply to http's xml response data ?
Which means I should use **xml.decode** to parse http.get response , rather than ioutil.ReadAll and xml.Unmarshal ?

Comment: how big is this "very long json"?

Comment: @ViniciusCardoso  Here is one json file with 20 articles, size is 1.1M. (-rw-rw-r-- 1 jia jia 1.1M May 21 10:15 nytimes-size.json) is it a very 'big' file for my solution above ? The size might increase if I want to retrieve more articles by increasing the url parameters. Any suggestions on a better solution ;)